# Differentiate between selected cell and edited cell

Tags: c++, qt

How to Differentiate between selected cell and edited cell in QTableModel.

Answer (score 0):

Selected items or cells can be viewed through the TableView's selection Model like so:

```
QModelIndexList indexes = view->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
```

This will give you a list of all indexes(cells) selected for a given View.

As far as Edited cell is concerned I don't think you can verify that it has been edited unless you catch the Delegate committing the information for the cell.  You can probably store it when you catch `commitData()` signal emitted by the Item's Delegate and store it internally somehow.